# Drupal.org issue tags: ciandt-contrib

Tags: community-official-site

Noticed the following tag being used on Drupal.org: `ciandt-contrib`. Either I'm completely missing something but I can't figure out what the `ciandt`abbreviation stands for. And when it should be used.

Is there perhaps also a list that explains more of those abstract issue tags?

Comment: Gonna take a stab that it's https://www.drupal.org/cit

Comment: *applies palm to face*. Indeed seems like you are right about it. I guess it's for the company to keep track on the issues they've worked on. I don't like the idea of using tags like that but whatever :), thanks @Clive !